# Equation of circle tangent to a circle and a line

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry, circles, problem-solving

Not sure if someone already asked this, but I am trying to find an equation of a circle. These are the information.

The circle $C$ is tangent to the circle $O$ with an equation $x^{2} + y^{2} = c^{2}$, and to the line $y = y_{1}$, which we name as $\ell_{1}$. Assume that $y_{1} > 0$, and the circle we choose is the "upper" circle.

The solution I made follows.

Suppose that the center of $C$ is at the point $(h,k)$ and a radius $r$. Then, by the properties of circles, the point of tangency of $O$ and $C$, the center of $C$ and the center of $O$ are collinear, and all points lie on the line $y = \frac{k}{h}x$, which we call $\ell_{2}$.

Solving for the intersection of $O$ and $\ell_{2}$, we get the points $\left(\dfrac{ch}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}, \dfrac{c}{k\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}\right)$ and $\left(-\dfrac{ch}{\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}, -\dfrac{c}{k\sqrt{h^{2} + k^{2}}}\right)$. However, the condition implies that the point needed is the former point. We name this point as $P_{1}$.

Since $\sqrt{h^{2}+k^{2}}$ is just equal to $c + r$. By substitution, we get that $P_{1}$ is $\left(\dfrac{ch}{c + r}, \dfrac{c}{k(c + r)}\right)$. Also, since $C$ is tangent to $\ell_{1}$, then it follows that the radius of $C$ is $k - y_{1}$. Thus, $P_{1} = \left(\dfrac{ch}{c + k - y_{1}}, \dfrac{c}{k(c + k - y_{1})}\right)$. This is the point where I was confused. How do I find the values of $h$, $k$, and $r$, in terms of $c$ and $y_{1}$? Or the given information is not enough?

Comment: There can be infinitely many circles satisfying the condition

Comment: Can I ask why there are infinitely many circles that can satisfy the condition?

Comment: Shall I post the images as solution?

Comment: If you like to, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There can be infinitely many circles. Play with the following graph to visualize it. You will get an answer.

[Cicrles tangent to another circle and a line](https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/rk6bwyax)

Note that the figure on which the centre of the circle moves is a parabola.

Comment: Can I ask what is the equation of circle $F$, please? It is the one I was looking for, exactly.

Comment: Yes. Also, I am curious if I move points $B$ and $C$.

Comment: Not to insist, but can I get $h$? I just want to know what is $h$, please.

Comment: It isn't constant. That is why I presented you the graphs. You can't solve it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113024/discussion-between-kevs924-and-soumyadwip-chanda).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

There are infinitely many solutions that you can obtain in following way:

- Pickup a real $r$ that will be the radius of the circle being solution.
- Find the intersections of the line of equation $y=y_1-r$ with the circle centered on the origin and with radius $c+r$.
- A circle centered on one of the points above with radius $r$ is a solution of your problem.

See image below[image: Geogebra image]

Comment: Can I try to actually see the graph in an interactive way, please?